# Exception when rendering Html.CheckBoxFor with invalid input: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean

Tags: c#, validation, model-view-controller

My MVC5 application is being scanned/spammed, and I'm getting 1,000's of exceptions in my logs. How can I resolve this?

Here's my model:

```cs
public class MyModel
{
  public bool IsRememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my view:

```cs
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsRememberMe)
```

Here's my action:

```cs
[HtmlPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    // Do work
  }

  return View(model);
}
```

When a spammer submits manually, a value such as "IsRememberMe=foo" in the POST, `ModelState.IsValid==false`, as expected and `model.IsRememberMe==false` as expected. However, when rendering the resulting view, `Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsRememberMe)` throws an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'System.Boolean' failed.

Inside the controller, if I add:

```cs
string value = ModelState["IsRememberMe"].Value.AttemptedValue;
```

then `value` equals `foo` (the input value).

Note that under normal conditions, everything is working correctly.

It looks like `Html.CheckBoxFor()` is pulling the value from `ModelState` rather than `model.IsRememberMe`.

What is the best way to resolve this?

#### Update

Based on the comments and feedback, it looks like the use of data from `ModelState` is by design. I'm OK with that under normal circumstances.

Some comments have suggested this is a duplicate. While the solution may be similar, I argue that it is not a duplicate since the problem I am trying to solve is different: I am not actively trying to change the submitted value in my controller.

I am trying to prevent an exception in MVC caused by the submission of invalid data. I am posting my own answer below.

Comment: `PostRedirectPattern`, redirect back to the GET action.

Comment: @mxmissile under what conditions do I perform the redirect? The  model has valid values. Must I iterate through `ModelState` and perform my own model validation to know whether to redirect or not?

Comment: `IsValid == false` if the other fields on the form failed validation. In that case, I don't want to redirect to back to GET. There, I want to return `View(model)` along with the model state errors so the user can retry.

Comment: Got it, this is indeed interesting, are you using AntiForgery?

Comment: Yes I am. I did not include it above, but I am using `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` on the action along with `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in the view. That part is working fine. This is not a forgery case. I can replicate this problem using PostMan or curl.

Comment: Check this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48204441/why-does-mvc-use-the-modelstate-over-a-supplied-model-on-a-get

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC 3 HtmlHelper.Textbox Uses ModelState as a source for value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640987/asp-net-mvc-3-htmlhelper-textbox-uses-modelstate-as-a-source-for-value)

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/simonince/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvcs-html-helpers-render-the-wrong-value/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this is a bug in the implementation of `Html.CheckBoxFor()`. Pulling the data from `ModelState` is fine, however, if the data cannot be converted, then it should fallback to using the value from the model instead of throwing an exception that halts rendering of the view.

I cannot think of a use-case where it's desirable to throw an exception (preventing rendering of the view) if the value in `ModelState` cannot be converted to a checked/unchecked for a checkbox. I'd be glad to hear from anyone who has such a use-case.

#### Solution

Due to the simplicity of the data type involved (`bool`), we can remove the value from `ModelState` if we are going to re-render the view. This will remove the offending value.

```cs
[HtmlPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    // Do work
  }

  if (ModelState.Keys.Contains("IsRememberMe"))
  {
    ModelState.Remove("IsRememberMe");
  }

  return View(model);
}
```